# How to draw on a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jlabel, java-2d

I want to use the 2D Java API to draw on a JLabel that already has an image on it and then save the resulting edited picture.

I can't find any tutorials on this specific subject, does anyone have any code or references that show how to do it?

Comment: Drawing in a JPanel is similar to drawing in any JComponent such as a JPanel. You can search this forum for many examples, shoot, many by me including [example 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575578/convert-a-graphics2d-to-an-image-or-bufferedimage/6575620#6575620), [example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081308/jpanel-custom-drawing-using-graphics/7081362#7081362), [example 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6105393/changing-jpanel-graphics-g-color-drawing-line/6105437#6105437)

Comment: and [example 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365535/best-to-handle-2-overlaying-live-updated-panels/7366478#7366478)

Comment: Thanks I'll have a good read!

Comment: Implementing `Icon` is a related approach, shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).

Comment: Please let me know if anything is confusing or if you're still stuck. You'll likely get some good direct answers here soon.

Comment: @trashgod: great posts and great suggestions. I've upvoted the one that I hadn't upvoted previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to render the existing image and drawing into a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), as shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2658663/230513) that overlays text on a logo. Once the image is complete, use [`ImageIO.write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to save it in the desired format.

Answer (score 5):

override the `paintComponent` method of the `JLabel`. It should first call `super.paintComponent`, so you get whatever the `JLabel` contains, then add your own drawing code after that. Should look somewhat like this:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g)
    g.drawWhatever ...
}
```